# How can split this symbols "*" in sentence

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner to Programming ,I want to know how can erase special symbol from the sentence without changing any word and any symbol in the sentence

**Example :**

Hi!!! how are you? I'm **** fine.   I want sentences  like that.. (**Hi!!! how are you? I'm fine.**)

erase * symbol

Answer should be used for Windows form application and in the example doesn't change !

Comment: check my answer machan

Comment: ape rate ekek wela.. ape ekage answer eka accept krnne neti .. ehema nownat 1st right answer eka blala accept  krnne neti,mage answer blala answer edit krpu ekage eka accept krna.. oya wage ayata answer daaanwata apita ghnna oni bn :|

Comment: mama answer eka check kara.mata hariyatama one wune windows applications walata match wena answer eakak.

Comment: wensa mokak d mage ekai ara anik yakage ekei :P u mage eka ehemma ghla class name ekat ekami, answer eka madi nam comment ekak dnna sup eka denwa kohomt pluwa widihata ape ayata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a specified character or substring from a string by calling the `String.Replace(String, String)` method and specifying an empty string `(String.Empty)` as the replacement. The following example removes all commas from a string.

```
using System;

    public class Example
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          String phrase = "a cold, dark night";
          Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", phrase);
          phrase = phrase.Replace(",", "");
          Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", phrase);
       }
    }
    // The example displays the following output:
    //       Before: a cold, dark night
    //       After: a cold dark night
```

Comment: reffer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples in Stack overflow and Web. Please refer it before asking a question here.
Below code will work for you.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
    string toBeReplaced = "Hi how are you? I'm ** fine.";        
    Console.WriteLine(toBeReplaced.Replace("*",""));
   }
}
```